# Makefile Syntax

Tags: makefile

I am learning about makefiles and am a bit confused about some of the syntax and how SUFFIXES work.

```
CPP = g++
OFLAG = -o
.SUFFIXES : .o .cpp .c
.cpp.o : 
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
.c.o :
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

all: \
    Return \
        Declare \
    Ifthen \    
    Guess \
    Guess2 \

Return: Return.o
    $(CPP) $(OFLAG)Return Return.o

Deckare: Declare.o
    $(CPP) $(OFLAG)Declare Declare.o

# follow same format for other executables

Return.o: Return.cpp
Declare.o: Declare.cpp

# follow same format for other executables
```

What does the line ".SUFFIXES : .o .cpp .c" actually do?

I do not quite understand what $< means.

Where does CPPFLAGS come from? (is it a special syntax just for make?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.SUFFIXES` defines the set of suffixes that make will understand for suffix rules.  So with this example, you can define suffix rules involving the suffixes `.o` `.cpp` and `.c`.  If you were to define a rule `.x.o`, since `.x` isn't in the `.SUFFIXES` list, it would not be a suffix rule -- it would instead be a rule to build the file `.x.o`

`$<` is short for `$(<)` and expands to the first dependency of the target in the current rule.

`$(CPPFLAGS)` is a make variable reference.  Since you don't set it in this makefile, it will expand to an empty string.  There's nothing particularly special about the name `CPPFLAGS` other than convention -- its generally the set of C pre-processor flags you want to pass to invokations of the c or c++ compiler, which is exactly how it is used here.

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` is "special" in this case in that make includes it in a number of its default rules.